# After calling my class's constructor, its properties are undefined

Tags: javascript, constructor

I have the following JavaScript:

```
function Parent(num, string) {
    this.num = num;
    this.string = string;
}

Parent.prototype.num = 0;
Parent.prototype.string = "";

function Child(num, string) {
    Parent.call(this);
}

Child.prototype = new Parent();
Child.prototype.constructor = Child;
```

When I create a new `Child`, its `num` and `string` fields are `undefined`:

```
> var child = new Child();
undefined
> child.num;
undefined
```

Why isn't the constructor setting the `Child`'s properties?

Comment: I know the answer to this question (see my answer below). I got tripped up for several hours on it and couldn't find anything on SO to help me figure out my problem. I know this is a newbie mistake, but hopefully this will be helpful to someone in the future.

Comment: It's easy to get fooled when you're writing code that is a little more complicated than usual, but here all you're really doing is calling a function without any arguments, and you're expecting arguments in the function, so yes, it's a newbie mistake, and I'm not sure why you think it would be useful to others, but that's up to you.

Comment: Dont you need this line as well? Child.prototype.constructor = Child;

Comment: @adeneo I (stupidly) wrote a whole bunch of JavaScript without testing it and was really confused by the symptoms in my question. Because I had so much code to look through, it was tough finding what I had missed =P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `Child` constructor, your call to `.call()` is missing the parameters you wish to send to the `Parent` constructor. You should have this instead:

```
function Child(num, string) {
    Parent.call(this, num, string);
}
```

With all of the parameters to send to the parent class's constructor after the first parameter.